# Using LESS files/libs in a SASS rails project?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, less

Or what is the best practice to "import" a less file in sass files?

I'm building a rails project with SASS as the solution for writing syntactic css. The SASS parts worked fine, until I find out that the styles of some open source projects are written in LESS and I really want to reuse their artwork.

Should I just let Rails precompile all LESS and SASS files, and `require` the result css files in a specified order?

The license of these third party projects are different. Understanding all the details about intellectual property laws seems to be too much work for the small project I'm doing (e.g. should I keep a css file MIT licensed if I changed 90% of it and just used the color palette?), this project will be open sourced as well, so I would like to keep the codes untouched for now.

**Update:** A easy way of translating all LESS files to SASS files would be nice as well.

Comment: For those who may concern, as last I converted the `.less` files with these [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19167099/1815491) and fixed some minor issues like sass `@extend` and file dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, [LESS & SASS are compiled differently](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/) (although are similar)

Would you be able to translate the LESS files you wish to include?

Comment: Translating LESS to SASS is acceptable, but I'm afraid it would led to a lot of debugging after the convention (tried manually with find-and-replace, ended with chaos). I have little experience with LESS, may I ask if translating LESS to SASS is a common way to do this?

Comment: For readability, I translate LESS to SASS all the time - it's very similar